Get the output of a failing update statement
I'm trying to solve the following problem, but can't get the output of a failing update statement:
I want to convert a list of hexadecimal IDs into a list of decimal IDs.
To avoid a CURSOR I want to do that with the following flow:
-- Test IDs, last one has an error
DECLARE @hexIDs AS VARCHAR(255) = '00000AAAAAA,00000BBBBBB,00000CCCCCC,X0000DDDDDD';

-- Table which holds hex IDs and converted IDs (necessary for feedback if something fails)
DECLARE @ids AS TABLE(IDHex VARCHAR(11), ID BIGINT);

-- Table to track updated ids
DECLARE @inserted AS TABLE(ID BIGINT);

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO @ids (IDHex) SELECT * FROM string_split(@hexIDs, ',');
    
    UPDATE @ids SET ID = CAST(CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0' + IDHex, 2) AS BIGINT)
      OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @inserted;
    
    SELECT * FROM @ids;
    SELECT * FROM @inserted;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  
      ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
      ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
      ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
      ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
      ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
      ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    SELECT * FROM @ids;
    SELECT * FROM @inserted;
END CATCH


As expected, the UPDATE fails because the last string ID is no hex value.
If I understand the Microsoft documentation right, the OUTPUT should work. But I can't figure out how. Can someone tell me how I can get the output of the UPDATE statement even if it fails?

If the UPDATE fails there there was no update, so there's nothing to OUTPUT. If you don't want a conversion error, why not use TRY_CONVERT/TRY_CAST?

Your hexadecimal values should have an even number of characters

Sry, I simplyfied the conversion for this post and deleted the " + '0'". With this it is even ;

@ThomA: The documentation says:
**Note
An UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement that has an OUTPUT clause will return rows to the client even if the statement encounters errors and is rolled back. The result shouldn't be used if any error occurs when you run the statement.**

But all rows will fail on CONVERT where, @SebUhb , so nothing UPDATEd.

The docs say The result shouldn't be used if any error occurs when you run the statement. but in next sentence you want to use output of the update statement

If you read the documentation you find out where you are going wrong. e.g.

Binary values must be an even number of chars long
You should always specify the length of VARBINARY whenever you use it.

Then you use TRY_CONVERT to only process rows which you can convert.
UPDATE @ids SET ID = CAST(TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(6), '0' + IDHex, 2) AS BIGINT)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @inserted
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(VARBINARY(6), '0' + IDHex, 2) IS NOT NULL;


Sorry I missed the style 2!  I always used style 1.

Thanks, this helps me a lot, I didn't know the TRY_CONVERT before. With this I can return not working IDs to the application. Because every entry with no conversion has a NULL in the ID column.
